# How to get files in AWS ECS' container?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

If want to get files in ECS' /tmp path, is it necessary to set a volume item to map the path?

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition#volume

Or is there a way to run something like `docker exec ...` to see the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand the question fully. You can "ecs exec" into a task (if that's what you want/need to do). Here is [the doc page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html) on how to do that and [this is a longer blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/new-using-amazon-ecs-exec-access-your-containers-fargate-ec2/) that dives into it.

If you instead need to pre-populate files in /tmp you have a couple of options. Either you pull them at container startup as part of a startup script. Or you mount the /tmp directory to an external share that hosts the data. [Here is how](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/).